# My Boss Wants Fancier Methods

Tags: teamwork, communication

I work in a young (< 3 year-old, <15 employees) startup. Our core data product is a recommendation engine. One of my primary responsibilities is to prototype the recommendation engine. Because the company is so young with very few clients, there are not many observed data (< 1000) in our system. We heavily rely on external data source to help with feature engineering and manually labeled data for validation. My philosophy is, using the dumbest and simplest method to get the framework out first. But my boss wants "more recognized" method, using his own definition "methods that discussed by some papers, widely evaluated in the community, and have existing tested implementations we can directly use". For example, in one model I simply used mean as an performance metric, and I think it is good enough for now, but he wants a much more complicated metric "discussed by some paper".  I am not arguing that what he wants isn't doable, but I am tired of explaining that, based on our current user engagement rate and amount of data we have, I really don't think that's the top priority.
In a small startup like this, I wear a lot of different hats and I think I have spread too thin.
I am wondering if anyone has been in the similar situation and how you dealt with it.

Comment: Make sure your "basic" calculation is in its own method or class, then put in a comment "TODO, implement XXX algorithm" along with a citation or URL to the algorithm

Comment: This doesn't sound like an engineering problem. It is a people problem. You might have better luck at https://workplace.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GregBurghardt will do, thanks!

Comment: @chchannn Before you post on workplace, delete the question here please.

Comment: When did talking with people fall out of our scope?

Comment: Boss decides what you should do in return for paying you. Just do it. Make it pluggable.

Answer (score 3):

> he wants a much more complicated metric

In engineering, complicated is not a goal. It may be a goal of marketing.

> discussed by some paper

It's difficult to say whether your boss is micromanaging and trying to improve the quality of work or if he's looking for a tech blurb he can brag about when talking to investors.

If you can, talk with him to get a better understanding of what's motivating him. As it stands right now you don't feel like this is helping the company.  You're not going to be very effective while you feel that way. See if you can resolve that.

Either way, the best reaction is to learn something fancy that may actually be useful yet not critical if it turns out to be worthless. Welcome to the world of research and development. Consider it another hat.

Comment: Talk with you boss. Try to understand the WHY behind his request, then work together to pursue that goal.
While you try to create the most effective solution for your "existing" customers, your boss might like to have the best selling solution. The latter is very important for a small start up.

Comment: @OliverMeyer better?

Comment: Yes. 

Took me a while to notice, that you changed your answer. I hit return too soon, so I only posted half of what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 3):

All the time. The way to deal with it is to understand and agree on the end goal.

Here your's is "get a working protype" and your boss's "create something that will impress investors"

These contradict each other, in that your quick solution begs the question, "Sure but anyone can buy datasets and do simple calcs on them. Why is your product worth money?" and your boss's solution has the obvious "That sounds great but can you show me something that actually works?" problem.

Get this out in the open and agree on a way forward that you both believe will succeed. And maybe trust your boss a bit more about the importance of these "marketing" factors.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

<sup>From Dilbert's *[What color do you want that database?](https://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-17)*</sup>

You can actually find some research paper, and implement the algorithm which it describes, after confirming with your manager that he really wants this (make sure you have his *written* agreement). Later on, when it makes matters way more complicated and requires to waste thousands of dollars on refactoring, use “I told you so” at your discression when and if it benefits you, in order to make sure your manager won't make technical decisions again.

Another way is to give your estimate about the cost of evaluating the research papers, and a rough estimate of writing an algorithm based on those research papers. If it takes ten man/days to just read a bunch of papers, this alone may discourage your manager, who probably doesn't want to pay you for reading and learning.

Or you can search for another job. Or do one of the two other solutions, *while* searching for another job.

Comment: Dilbert does not work in a small startup. Do not assume, chchannn's boss is pointy haired. "I told you so" does not help the company. Leaving does not help the company. chchannn is part of the company.

Comment: @OliverMeyer: what makes you think chchannn wants or needs to help the company? His interests are not necessarily his company interests, and his role in the company doesn't necessarily make it possible to help the company anyway in the current situation. As for the “I told you so,” it may actually help in order to establish the management limits and preventing the manager from taking decisions he doesn't have the skills to take.

Comment: I understand an employee to be part of a company, especially in a small startup. If I do not want to be part of the company, I should work as a freelancer.